# How to change default username in Window Authentication in ssms

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I want to change Username in Window Authentication. HHAX\npatel to XYZ\patel.

I want single time configuration not to run from run command.

[image]

Basically I have multiple server and I can access with window authentication with another user and I can not able to change it.

So I want to change username.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you asking:  I am I logged onto my machine as HHAX\npatel and want to open SSMS with xyz\patel?   This will allow you login to any server as you xyz\patel.   And you are saying that shift-right-click (on ssms) | Run as Different user is not a suitable solution?

Comment: runas /netonly /user:xyz\patel ssms.exe is not working in my case. Shift + Right click also not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use `runas /noprofile /netonly /user:somedomain\someuser` the connection dialog box still displays as the local user, but it will in fact use the alternate credentials to make the connection.

You don't have to type it from command line every time, just create .cmd batch files, one for each server you need to connect to, with the contents:

```
runas /noprofile /netonly /user:somedomain\someuser "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 18\Common7\IDE\Ssms.exe"
```

Substitute your SSMS installation path if it is different. Stick 'em in a folder on the desktop. You can even keep the SSMS icon by creating a shortcut and setting the icon in the shortcut.

Comment: My Management Studio was crashing with a visual studio error message when I try to run it with a different user but this works!